# Who is the user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm starting to learn the basics of developing database applications (I want to learn MySQL specifically), but I'm unable to determine how the structure of the application should be. Say my system serves the students of a school (records grades, etc.), where the client side is a GUI application written in C++/Qt talking to my server computer over the internet.

My question is What is the natural/correct way to implement this?

- Do I encapsulate the SQL queries directly in the GUI program, and
  thus making every student a user of the MySQL database, and thus
  assigning a database user for each student?
- Or should the encapsulation occur in a server side application that I
  write that represents the link between the GUI application and the database
  server? (I.e. the server side application is the client side of the
  MySQL system.)

In other words, who is the user of MySQL? My server side application or the users of my client side application?

Comment: Both are possible, but the latter is the more typical. It lets you better handle authorization - users presumably shouldn't be able to adjust *everyone's* grades, for example.

Comment: I see this as more of a dba question

Comment: @Strawberry How can I request migrating the question, if possible?

Answer (score 3):

In both cases (wide client -- client-DB or thin client -- client-server) it is enough to have only 1 MySQL user.
You will store it's user and password in application settings (usually hidden from regular student/customer).
And you will grant those rights to application username, not to the student.

It is the role of application to control the user rights.

Safety:
For the thin client, it is usually safe, but it will introduce the need to use API-key that has its danger.
For wide client architecture it is dangerous enough, so:

- usually, such applications work in-house
- MySQL user has those rights that protect the data from full destroying (at least forbid tables dropping).
- grant privileges to the user on SPECIFIC HOSTs
- make backup copies on the hourly or daily basis depends on the
  size
- it is good to store the password, not in open form but
  encrypted

Comment: Is it safe or commonly practiced to store a unique username/password (that has an authority over the data) inside the binary of the product shipped to the users?

Comment: for client-server it is usually safe, but it will introduce the need to use API-key that has its danger.
For client-DB architecture it is dangerous enough, so: 
1) usually such applications works in-house 
2) MySQL user has that rights that protect the data from full destroying.
3) it is good to store the password, not in open form but encrypted